# Update multiple Cols Different Row Same Table

Tags: psql

This works:

```
UPDATE tracks 
SET (artist, lyrics) = 
('Last, First', 'none yet') 
WHERE id = 127;
```

And this works:

```
UPDATE tracks 
SET lyrics =                      
(SELECT lyrics FROM tracks WHERE id = 64)
WHERE id = 127;
```

This one's returning an error (near `lyrics) =`)

```
UPDATE tracks 
SET (artist, lyrics) =    
    (SELECT artist, lyrics 
    FROM tracks
    WHERE id = 64)
WHERE id = 127;
```

How do I return the sub-query in a format that the outer query can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgotten to put your table in your query:

```
UPDATE tracks 
SET (artist, lyrics) =    
    (SELECT 
           artist, 
           lyrics 
     FROM #your_tablename_here
     WHERE id = 64)
WHERE id = 127;
```

Edit:
Try to separate your update fields. See below:

```
UPDATE tracks 
    SET artist = (SELECT artist FROM tracks WHERE id = 64),
        lyrics = (SELECT lyrics FROM tracks WHERE id = 64)
WHERE id = 127;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was only a mistake in the actual post. Question corrected. Error is `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"`.

Comment: Separating the fields works. I want to give the Derived Table answer a chance (if it gets corrected) though, before "accepting". Thank you.

Comment: Of course, I got syntax errors on the versions you said worked.  So I assume we are using different DB systems.

Comment: Did the Derived Table works? If not just use my answer. Thanks!

Comment: My mistake, @JimMc - MySQL was not supposed to be tagged. I'm using psql. I bet something along the lines of your recommendation would be the more sophisticated, if not more optimal approach to the multiple sub-queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE tracks 
SET (artist, lyrics) =    
    (SELECT artist, lyrics 
    FROM [Put your table name here]
    WHERE id = 64)
WHERE id = 127;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was only a mistake in the actual post. Question corrected. Error is `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"`.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:

```
UPDATE tracks 
JOIN (/* Derived table */
SELECT tx.artist, tx.lyrics
    FROM tracks tx
    WHERE id = 64
 ) dt
SET tracks.artist=dt.artist, tracks.lyrics =  dt.lyrics 
WHERE id = 127;
```

Comment: something not quite right: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "join"`